# Know available versions of dependencies in Maven

Tags: android, maven, android-architecture-components

I want to know what are the available versions, given a maven repository.

The URL is https://maven.google.com OR https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/

Specifically, I want to "explore" the Maven Google Repository, for Android Architecture Components. I know that Android Studio sometimes warns you if a new version is available, but I want to explore for myself. I've tried

- Exploring the repo via web (HTTP / HTTPS), including exploring subpaths like /pom.xml, /.index, /maven-metadata.xml and so on (just guessing)
- Installed Eclipse and NetBeans, and use both integrated maven repositories explorer. No luck, no errors given.
- Exploring Google Docs (outdated), see [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components.html) and [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html)

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Could you be more specific and give examples what you are trying to achieve? There are Maven goals for updating versions of given artifacts, but I do not know what you mean by "exploring".

Comment: @JFMeier By exploring, I mean view the available versions of an artifact in a repo. For example: artifact 'foo' has versions { 1.0.0, 1.0.1 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install your own Nexus/Artifactory (if do not already have one), and add the google repositories as proxy repositories. Then you can use the browser interface to make granular searches, including the one you gave in your comment.

Comment: Ok, I see. But I was thinking more like a lightweight approach. This seems to heavy to me. Thanks anyway, I didn't know that was possible ;)

Comment: If you are lucky, the google repositories have a web interface (as maven central) in which can search.